# Passing Variables to/from Modal

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, modal-dialog, react-functional-component, react-portal

I implemented a Modal which uses a custom Hook in my App that should function as a login mask for a WiFi network. So far the Modal is working and I also already managed to pass the name of the selected SSID to it. However I'm struggling with getting back a variable into my other component from where I launched the modal.

Modal.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';



const Modal = ({ isShowing, connect, ssid, hide }) => isShowing ? createPortal(

    <React.Fragment>
        <div className="modal-overlay" />
        <div className="modal-wrapper" aria-modal aria-hidden tabIndex={-1} role="dialog">
            <div className="modal">
                <div className="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" className="modal-close-button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onClick={hide}>
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-body">
                    <p>Connect to: {ssid}</p>
                    <label>
                        <form onSubmit={connect}>
                            <input
                                id="password"
                                name="Password"
                                type="password"
                                value={"password"}
                            />
                            <button type="submit">Connect</button>
                        </form>
                    </label>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>, document.getElementById("modal")
) : null;

export default Modal;
```

useModal.js:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const useModal = () => {
  const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState(false);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("password");

  function toggle() {
    setPassword("HOW");
    setIsShowing(!isShowing);
  }

  return {
    password,
    isShowing,
  }
};

export default useModal;
```

Settings.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Modal from "../../components/Modal";
import useModal from "../../components/useModal";

const electron = window.require('electron');
const { ipcRenderer } = electron;


const Settings = ({ reqReload }) => {

  const [wifiList, setWifiList] = useState([{ id: "", ssid: 'No Networks available' }]);
  const [ssidSelected, setSsidSelected] = useState("127.0.0.1");
  const { isShowing, toggle } = useModal();


  const updateWifi = (event, args) => {
    setWifiList(args);
  };

  function openDialogue(ssid) {
    setSsidSelected(ssid);
    toggle();
  };
  /*
  function connectWifi(password) {
    console.log("Aktuelles Passwort: ", password);
    toggle();
  }
  */

  useEffect(() => {
    ipcRenderer.send('updateWifi');
    ipcRenderer.on('wifi_list', updateWifi);

    return function cleanup() {
      ipcRenderer.removeListener('wifi_list', updateWifi);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="settings">
      <Modal
        isShowing={isShowing}
        connect={connectWifi}
        ssid={ssidSelected}
        hide={toggle}
      />
      <div className="settings__header">
        <h2></h2>
      </div>
      <div className="settings__body">
        <div className="settings__connections">
          <div className="settings__connections__wifi">
            <p><i>Available Wifi-Networks:</i></p>
            <div className="settings__connections__wifi__list">
              {wifiList.map((item, i) => (
                <div className="settings__connections__wifi__list__item" key={i}>
                  <button className="selectNetworkButton" type="button" onClick={() => openDialogue(item.ssid)}>{item.ssid}</button>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};

export default Settings;
```

The code above already contains some things I tried. As stated before, passing the SSID to the modal worked, but I dont have a clue how to get the password back to Settings.js to handle the data there.

I'd be happy if someone can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

in order to get back a variable from a child component, you can have the variable you would like to get back as a state in your parent component:

```
const [yourVariable, setYourVariable] = useState('')
```

then pass `setYourVariable` as a props to your modal.
this way you can set `youVariable` from inside the modal component, and get back its value this way :

```
// inside modal component 
 setYoutVariable(...)
```

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't get it. The part of fetching the data from the form in combination with this is making me blind somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over another article just now and it seems like using a stateless component as my model leads to a dead end. Will have to convert it to a stateful component in order to extract the data from the form.